# How to write $a=b\Leftrightarrow c=d\Leftrightarrow e=f$ is the expression does not fit a single line?

Tags: notation

I am currently showing that $a=b\Leftrightarrow e=f$ by showing that $a=b\Leftrightarrow c=d\Leftrightarrow e=f$. The problem that I have is that the expressions $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ are rather long and do not fit in a single line. I am currently writing this:
\begin{gather}
a=b\\
c=d\\
e=f
\end{gather}
But I am wondering whether I should instead write this:
\begin{gather}
a=b\Leftrightarrow\\
c=d\Leftrightarrow\\
e=f
\end{gather}
Or perhaps even this:
\begin{gather}
a=b\Leftrightarrow\\
\Leftrightarrow c=d\Leftrightarrow\\
\Leftrightarrow e=f
\end{gather}
Hence, how should I **write $a=b\Leftrightarrow c=d\Leftrightarrow e=f$ if the expression does not fit a single line?**

Thank you all in advanced for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably write

$$
\begin{align*}
a &= b \\ \iff c &= d \\ \iff e &= f
\end{align*}
$$

Usually arrows at the beginning of the line read most naturally, in my opinion. If you're asking about LaTeX, this is done with the "align" environment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me ask you something: why $\Longleftrightarrow$ rather than $\Leftrightarrow$?

Comment: I just prefer and generally choose to use $\iff$ which is "\iff" in LaTeX, but you can also use $\Leftrightarrow$.

Answer (score 3):

You can put labels on the three equations :
$$a=b\,\,\,(1)$$
$$c=d\,\,\,(2)$$
$$e=f\,\,\,(3)$$
And then use
$$(1)\Leftrightarrow (2)\Leftrightarrow (3).$$